# Equal time between rows with R

Tags: r, date, time, difference

I have the following sample:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(mmsi = c(992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 
992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 
992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 
992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L), timestamp_pretty = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 19L), .Label = c("15/01/2015 00:02:06", "15/01/2015 00:05:09", 
"15/01/2015 00:08:02", "15/01/2015 00:11:04", "15/01/2015 00:14:02", 
"15/01/2015 00:17:06", "15/01/2015 00:20:07", "15/01/2015 00:23:05", 
"15/01/2015 00:26:04", "15/01/2015 00:32:09", "15/01/2015 00:35:02", 
"15/01/2015 00:38:05", "15/01/2015 00:41:06", "15/01/2015 00:44:02", 
"15/01/2015 00:47:03", "15/01/2015 00:50:03", "15/01/2015 00:53:18", 
"15/01/2015 00:56:07", "15/01/2015 00:59:07"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("mmsi", 
"timestamp_pretty"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

I would like to remove some of the signals and to keep only signals every 6 minutes.

I have the following function that will should select the signals every 6 minutes

```
library(chron)
library(zoo)
to180ch <- function(x) trunc(as.chron(as.character(x), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), "00:06:00")
for ( i in levels(data$mmsi) ){
  read.zoo(data, FUN = to180ch, aggregate = function(x) tail(x, 1))}

test <- subset(data, !duplicated(to180ch(timestamp_pretty), fromLast = TRUE))
test <- test[order(test$mmsi, test$timestamp_pretty),]
```

but when I check the time difference in minutes between the signals, I sometimes have less than 6 minutes:

```
test<-data.table(test)
test[, timestamp_pretty:=as.POSIXct( timestamp_pretty, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC" )]
test[,diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty:=c(NA,diff(timestamp_pretty)),by="mmsi"]
```

I got as final result:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(mmsi = c(992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 
992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 992761085L, 
992761085L, 992761085L), timestamp_pretty = structure(c(1421280309, 
1421280664, 1421281026, 1421281385, 1421281564, 1421282102, 1421282466, 
1421282823, 1421283198, 1421283547, 1421283910, 1421284278), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty = c(NA, 
5.91666666666667, 6.03333333333333, 5.98333333333333, 2.98333333333333, 
8.96666666666667, 6.06666666666667, 5.95, 6.25, 5.81666666666667, 
6.05, 6.13333333333333)), .Names = c("mmsi", "timestamp_pretty", 
"diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty"), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

In the column `diff_time_seconds_timestamp_pretty` (difference in minutes between the signals), I have for example 5,91 minutes; 5,8 minutes or even 2.9 minutes! I guess there is a problem with the filtering of the "at least 6 minutes".

How can I have at least 6 minutes between the signals?

Thank you

Comment: Are you just trying to have at least 6 minutes between rows or are you trying to keep the row that is closest to **next** 6 minute mark since 0? There is a difference and I believe your code achieves the latter and not necessarily the former.

Comment: I try to get the closer as possible to every 6 minutes, so the second idea you gave. I don´t want to edit the data with having exactly every 6 minutes a signal.

Comment: Well, I believe your code does do that. It is just that in the next 6 minute time window, there may be a signal that is within 6 minutes from your last signal. For example, `20:07` and `23:05` are within the window from `18:00` and `24:00`, so you keep `23:05`, and you only have `26:04` in the window from `24:00` to `30:00` so you also keep that, but it is within `6` minutes from `23:05`.

Comment: Exactly. I think this is actually the solution to what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

```
library("data.table")

data$timestamp_pretty <- as.POSIXct( data$timestamp_pretty, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC" )
```

6 minutes = 6*60 = 360 seconds

If you need signals less than or equal to 6 minutes:

```
setDT(data)[, .(timestamp_pretty, diff = c(0, diff(data$timestamp_pretty))), by = mmsi][diff <= 360, .SD, .SDcols = c("timestamp_pretty"), by = mmsi]

#        mmsi    timestamp_pretty
# 1: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:02:06
# 2: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:05:09
# 3: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:08:02
# 4: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:11:04
# 5: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:14:02
# 6: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:17:06
# 7: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:20:07
# 8: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:23:05
# 9: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:26:04
# 10: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:35:02
# 11: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:38:05
# 12: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:41:06
# 13: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:44:02
# 14: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:47:03
# 15: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:50:03
# 16: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:53:18
# 17: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:56:07
# 18: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:59:07
# 19: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:59:07
```

If you need signals at least 6 minutes:

```
setDT(data)[, .(timestamp_pretty, diff = c(0, diff(data$timestamp_pretty))), by = mmsi][diff >= 360, .SD, .SDcols = c("timestamp_pretty"), by = mmsi]

#         mmsi    timestamp_pretty
# 1: 992761085 2015-01-15 00:32:09
```

Comment: the solution for the signals at least 6 minutes could fit, but here it is removing too much signals :)

Comment: It's based on your question. Please explain with examples.

Comment: The first signal in every group of mmsi will be removed, because we assign 0 to it. Does this cause to loose signals?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want 6-minute-steps from your first value on. Here is my approach:
I put your data in the example data frame. First I convert it to POSIX, so I can do arithmetic operation on the time stamps.

```
example$timestamp_pretty <-
as.POSIXct(example$timestamp_pretty,
           tz = Sys.timezone(location = TRUE),
           "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Second, I create a vector of exact 6-minute-steps from the first value on, from the lowest time value to the highest in 6*60 second steps.

```
stamps <- 
seq(from = example$timestamp_pretty[1],
    to = example$timestamp_pretty[length(example$timestamp_pretty)],
    by = 6*60)
```

Than I search the indexes of the time stamps that are the nearest ones to the exact ones.

```
nearest <- sapply(stamps,function(x)which.min(abs(x - example$timestamp_pretty)))
```

In the last step I subset the data by the indexes.

```
example <- example[nearest, ]
```

As you can see, they are close:

```
    example$stamps <- stamps
    > example
        mmsi    timestamp_pretty              stamps
1  992761085 2015-01-15 00:02:06 2015-01-15 00:02:06
3  992761085 2015-01-15 00:08:02 2015-01-15 00:08:06
5  992761085 2015-01-15 00:14:02 2015-01-15 00:14:06
7  992761085 2015-01-15 00:20:07 2015-01-15 00:20:06
9  992761085 2015-01-15 00:26:04 2015-01-15 00:26:06
10 992761085 2015-01-15 00:32:09 2015-01-15 00:32:06
12 992761085 2015-01-15 00:38:05 2015-01-15 00:38:06
14 992761085 2015-01-15 00:44:02 2015-01-15 00:44:06
16 992761085 2015-01-15 00:50:03 2015-01-15 00:50:06
18 992761085 2015-01-15 00:56:07 2015-01-15 00:56:06
```

EDIT: In the comments you mentioned you want to start with 0. I think your data don´t show where this could be. So I thought it means your first value.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got almost the same result than the solution I posted, very good. The difference is that you keep the first signal (row), and I don´t. I will try to run yours depending on the mmsi (factor).